# Table Outer Body only in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display only table outer border when that option is clicked. The code is implemented using extjs and html. Border attribute has 2 values 1 and 0 which shows the borders or hides it. How can i implement it for outer borders.

This is the function to generate table.

```
generateHtmlTable = function (cols, rows, border) {
//Create Table
var tdWidth = 100 / cols;
var classN;
//break-word only for IE
//Set the classes for each type of table
if(border==1){
    classN = "table1";
} else {
    classN = "table0";
}
var tempborder = "box";
var table = "<table bgColor=white border='"+border+"' width='100%' style=\"table-layout:auto word-wrap: break-word;\" class=\"" + classN +"\" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
for (var i = 0; i< parseInt(rows); i++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < parseInt(cols); j++) {
        table += "<td class=\"" + classN +"\" width='" + tdWidth +"%' valign=\"top\">&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
}
table += "</table>";
return table;
```

}

This is the function to set borders.

```
setOutBorder: function(edt){
        var rng = edt.getDoc().getSelection().anchorNode;
        if (tables.validNode(rng)) {
            tables.init(edt);
            for(var i = 0; i < tbody.childNodes.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++){
                    tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].className = "table0";
                }
            }
            table.className = "tableOut";
            table.border = 0;
            //rng.select();
        }
        tables.refresh(edt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show hide table border based on value, may be using jQuery can apply based on condition.

```
if(border)//is one
{
 $(<get table by class or id>).css({border:'1px solid black'});
}
else 
{
 $(<get table by class or id>).css({border:none});
}
```

```js
function showHideBorder(border)
{
  if(border == 1)
    {
      $('.isBordered').css({border:'1px solid'});
    }
  else
    {
      $('.isBordered').css({border:'none'});
    }
}


$('#btn1').click(function(){
  showHideBorder(1);
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
  showHideBorder(0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class='isBordered'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Hello
      </td>
      <td>
        Anirudh Lakshmeesh
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Hope!
      </td>
      <td>
        It worked
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button id='btn1'>Show</button>
    <button id='btn2'>Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean, border only for table not for td/tr is it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want only table borders not for td and tr.

Comment: Ideally it should apply only for table. Not for td & tr.

Comment: Can you add snippet, so that what is the issue we can figure out

Comment: I have attached the code snippet in my question. Function to generate HTML Table borders and Function to set table border by sending 0 / 1 as prams.

Comment: I think issue might be with table0/table1 class i think

Comment: .table0 {border: #d3d3d3 1px dotted; font-size:9pt; important!}                               .table1 {border: solid 1px black; font-size:9pt; important!}

Comment: Ya.. Issue is here.. You are applying table1 & table0 to td.. Not to table.. SO obviously, it will add border for td.. Instead of table.. See the executable snippet added here.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your support. I applied table0 to my <table> as well. unfortunately didn't work. Might be some bug with my editor. I am using ExtJs

Comment: Ideally should not be.. Bcoz its with css.. Not about editor. Try not to apply css for td